# Passing a comma separate String constant to a method in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy and need to achieve following, I have defined a constant as

`static String listOfAllFields = "Field1","Field2","Field3"`

I am passing this variable in a method `verifyFields(listOfAllFields)` and the method implementation is

```
def verifyFields(String... fields) {
  fields.each {
    //do something
  }
}
```

if I pass like this `verifyFields("Field1","Field2,"Field3")` the method works but if I have to pass these through a variable, how do I achieve? how do I pass the "," separated values as a List in groovy to `listOfAllFields`.

Answer (score 1):

you just use `list literal` for that

```
static listOfAllFields = [ "Field1","Field2","Field3" ]
```

then you can use a `spread operator` to pass it into the method:

```
verifyFields( *listOfAllFields )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your constant is a String as opposed to a List, [the `split` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) should suffice.

```
static final String ALL_FIELDS = 'Field1,Field2,Field3'
verifyFields(ALL_FIELDS.split(','))
```